# Using GDAL in C++. Create multiple GDALDatasets using a GDALDriver produces error 4 not recognised as a supported file format

Tags: gdal, c++, visual-studio

I am trying to create multiple GDALDataset objects. All of them are supposed to be in the .tif format, so for all of them I use the same GDALDriver.

I am working in C++ (Visual Studio) and when I build the solution there are no errors. But when I run it, I get the following error:

Error 4 'filename.tif' not recognised as a supported file format

The weird thing is that f I run the code consecutive times without changing anything, the GDALDataset for which I get the error change randomly. Sometimes I get the error for 5 of the 10 I am creating, sometimes for 9, etc.

I also have an additional question. When I check the tutorials in the GDAL website, when they create an object they have two different ways. For instance, creating a GDALDataset they have this two formats:

```
GDALDataset* PredictionRaster = (GDALDataset *) IMGdriver->Create("PredictionRaster.tif",XSize,YSize,1,TempBnd->GetRasterDataType(),NULL);
```

or

```
GDALDataset* PredictionRaster =  IMGdriver->Create("PredictionRaster.tif",XSize,YSize,1,TempBnd->GetRasterDataType(),NULL);
```

What is the (GDALDataset *) right after the assignment operator?

I also saw that in the initialization of the driver:

```
GDALDriver* IMGdriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
```

or

```
GDALDriver* IMGdriver = (GDALDriver*) GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
```

Here are two images showing how the error is random executing exactly the same code and the same build:

[image]

[image]

For reference, here is the code I am talking about:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "gdal_alg.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"
#include "cpl_string.h"
#include <ogr_spatialref.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>


class LC_Raster
{
private: 
    std::string m_parentProductName;
    int m_year;
    std::string m_rasterName;
    GDALDataset* m_SourceRasterDS;

public:
    LC_Raster(): m_parentProductName("NLCD"), m_year(2001)
    {
        std::stringstream os;
        os << m_year;

        std::string yearAsString;
        os >> yearAsString;

        m_rasterName = "Recon_" + m_parentProductName + "_" + yearAsString + ".tif";

        m_SourceRasterDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(m_rasterName.c_str(),GA_ReadOnly);
    }
    LC_Raster(std::string parentProductName , int year ): m_parentProductName(parentProductName), m_year(year)
    {
        std::stringstream os;
        os << m_year;

        std::string yearAsString;
        os >> yearAsString;

        m_rasterName = "Recon_" + m_parentProductName + "_" + yearAsString + ".tif";

        m_SourceRasterDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(m_rasterName.c_str(),GA_ReadOnly);
    }

    void setProductName (std::string name)
    {
        m_parentProductName = name;
    }

    void setRasterYear (int year)
    {
        m_year = year;
    }

    std::string getParentProductName () {return m_parentProductName; }
    int getRasterYear () {return m_year; }
    std::string getFileName () {return m_rasterName; }
    GDALDataset* getRasterGDAL () {return m_SourceRasterDS; }
};




class LC_Product
{
private:
    std::string m_productName;
    std::vector<int> m_productYears;
    int m_numberOfRasetrs;
    std::vector<LC_Raster> m_rastersOfProduct;

public:
    LC_Product(): m_productName("Default_NLCD")
    {
        int arrayYearsNLCD[] = {2001,2006,2011};
        std::vector<int> yearsNLCD (arrayYearsNLCD, arrayYearsNLCD + sizeof(arrayYearsNLCD) / sizeof(int) );
        m_productYears = yearsNLCD;

        m_numberOfRasetrs = yearsNLCD.size();
        m_rastersOfProduct.resize(yearsNLCD.size());

        for (int iii=0; iii < yearsNLCD.size(); iii++)
        {
            m_rastersOfProduct[iii] = LC_Raster("NLCD",yearsNLCD[iii]);
        }

    }

    LC_Product(std::string productName, std::vector<int> productYears): m_productName(productName), m_productYears(productYears)
    {
        m_numberOfRasetrs = productYears.size();
        m_rastersOfProduct.resize(productYears.size());

        for (int iii=0; iii < productYears.size(); iii++)
        {
            m_rastersOfProduct[iii] = LC_Raster(productName,productYears[iii]);
        }

    }

    std::string getProductName () {return m_productName; }
    std::vector<int> getProductYears () {return m_productYears; }
    int getNumberOfRasters () {return m_numberOfRasetrs; }

    LC_Raster getRaster (int year)
    {
        for (int iii = 0; iii < m_productYears.size(); iii++)
        {
            if (m_productYears[iii] == year)
            {
                return m_rastersOfProduct[iii];
            }
        }

        bool yearNotFound = 0;

        assert (yearNotFound);
    }

    std::vector<int> calculateNeighboringYears (int yearToPredict, int deltaT)
    {
        std::vector <int> neighborYears;
        int numberOfNeighboringYears = neighborYears.size(); //This is the same as 0

        for (int iii=0; iii < m_productYears.size(); iii++)
        {
            if ((m_productYears[iii] >= (yearToPredict-deltaT)) && (m_productYears[iii] <= (yearToPredict+deltaT)))
            {
                numberOfNeighboringYears += 1;
                neighborYears.resize(numberOfNeighboringYears);
                neighborYears[numberOfNeighboringYears-1] = m_productYears[iii];
            }
        }

        return neighborYears;
    }
};




class LC_SetOfProducts
{
private:
    std::array<std::string,6> m_productNames;
    std::array<LC_Product,6> m_products;


public:
    LC_SetOfProducts()
    {
        m_productNames[0]="BC";
        m_productNames[1]="Hist";
        m_productNames[2]="LF";
        m_productNames[3]="MODIS";
        m_productNames[4]="NLCD";
        m_productNames[5]="NLCD92";
        //Vectors with the year of eahc product
        std::vector<int> yearsBC;
        for (int yearBC = 1938; yearBC <= 2005; yearBC++)
        {
            yearsBC.push_back(yearBC);
        }
        std::vector<int> yearsHist (1,1977);
        int arrayYearsLF[] = {2001,2008,2010,2012};
        std::vector<int> yearsLF (arrayYearsLF, arrayYearsLF + sizeof(arrayYearsLF) / sizeof(int) );
        std::vector<int> yearsMODIS;
        for (int yearMODIS = 2001; yearMODIS <= 2012; yearMODIS++)
        {
            yearsMODIS.push_back(yearMODIS);
        }
        int arrayYearsNLCD[] = {2001,2006,2011};
        std::vector<int> yearsNLCD (arrayYearsNLCD, arrayYearsNLCD + sizeof(arrayYearsNLCD) / sizeof(int) );
        std::vector<int> yearsNLCD92 (1,1992);

        //initilize array of products

        m_products[0] = LC_Product(m_productNames[0],yearsBC);
        m_products[1] = LC_Product(m_productNames[1],yearsHist);
        m_products[2] = LC_Product(m_productNames[2],yearsLF);
        m_products[3] = LC_Product(m_productNames[3],yearsMODIS);
        m_products[4] = LC_Product(m_productNames[4],yearsNLCD);
        m_products[5] = LC_Product(m_productNames[5],yearsNLCD92);

    }

    std::array<LC_Product,6> getArrayOfProducts () {return m_products; }
    std::array<std::string,6> getArrayOfProductNames () {return m_productNames; }

    LC_Product getProductFromName (std::string name)
    {
        for (int iii = 0; iii < m_products.size(); iii++)
        {
            if (m_productNames[iii] == name)
            {
                return m_products[iii];
            }
        }
        bool nameNotFound = 0;

        assert (nameNotFound);
    }
};



class Probability_Raster
{
private: 
    int m_LC_type;
    GDALDataset* m_RasterDS;
    int m_XSize;
    int m_YSize;
    std::string m_fileName;

public:
    Probability_Raster( int LC_type, int XSize, int YSize, double GeoTransformProbability[6], const char *probabilityProjection, GDALDriver* IMGdriver): m_LC_type(LC_type), m_XSize(XSize), m_YSize(YSize)
    {
        std::stringstream os;
        os << LC_type;
        std::string LC_TypeAsString;
        os >> LC_TypeAsString;
        m_fileName = "ProbabilityRaster_" + LC_TypeAsString + ".tif";

        GDALDataset* ProbabilityRasterGDAL = IMGdriver->Create(m_fileName.c_str(),XSize,YSize,1,GDALDataType::GDT_Float32,NULL);

        ProbabilityRasterGDAL->SetGeoTransform(GeoTransformProbability);
        ProbabilityRasterGDAL->SetProjection(probabilityProjection);
        m_RasterDS = ProbabilityRasterGDAL;
    }

    int getLC_type () {return m_LC_type; }
    std::string getFileName () {return m_fileName; }
    GDALDataset* getRasterGDAL () {return m_RasterDS; }
};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Register all the formats that the GDAL library supports, including .tif files
    GDALAllRegister();

    //Load the set of products used in this project: BC, Hist, NLCD, LF, MODIS, NLCD92
    LC_SetOfProducts products;

    //Define the size of neighboring window in meters and years
    double windSizeX = 500;
    double windSizeY = 500;
    double windSizeT = 5;

    //Create array with the LC classes (9 for this case)
    const int numOf_LC_classes = 9;
    std::array<int,numOf_LC_classes> LCclasses = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};


    //
    /*Creation of empty raster where we would predict land cover*/
    //

    //In this case the raster has the same resolution and number of cells as NLCD
    //Number of cells in the new raster

    GDALRasterBand* TempBnd = products.getProductFromName("NLCD").getRaster(2001).getRasterGDAL()->GetRasterBand(1);
    int XSize = TempBnd->GetXSize();
    int YSize = TempBnd->GetYSize();

    std::cout << "The size of the prediction raster is (number of X cells, number of Y cells):\n";
    std::cout << XSize << ", " << YSize << "\n";

    //First, specify the driver (format) that the new raster would have (.tif again)
    //GDALDriver* IMGdriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    GDALDriver* IMGdriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    //Crate the GDAL raste robject for the prediction raster
    GDALDataset* PredictionRaster = (GDALDataset *) IMGdriver->Create("PredictionRaster.tif",XSize,YSize,1,TempBnd->GetRasterDataType(),NULL);

    //Create the geotransformation for the prediction raster (it is taken from NLCD product and can be modified)
    //Geotransformation has the coordinates of top left corner, and the resolution of the raster
    double GeoTransformPrediction[6]; 
    products.getProductFromName("NLCD").getRaster(2001).getRasterGDAL()->GetGeoTransform(GeoTransformPrediction);
    /*GeoTransformPrediction[1]=1000; //Uncomment if you want to change cell size of prediction raster*/
    /*GeoTransformPrediction[5]=-1500; //Uncomment if you want to change cell size of prediction raster*/
    PredictionRaster->SetGeoTransform(GeoTransformPrediction);

    //Create the projection for the prediction raster (it is taken from NLCD product)
    const char *predictionProjection = products.getProductFromName("NLCD").getRaster(2001).getRasterGDAL()->GetProjectionRef();
    PredictionRaster->SetProjection(predictionProjection);


    //
    /*Creation of empty rasters where we would predict probabilities for each land cover category (one raster per category)*/
//

    std::vector<Probability_Raster> vectorOfProbabilityRasters;

    for (int iii = 0; iii < numOf_LC_classes; iii++)
    {
        vectorOfProbabilityRasters.push_back(Probability_Raster( (iii+1),  XSize,  YSize, GeoTransformPrediction, predictionProjection, IMGdriver ));
        std::cout << vectorOfProbabilityRasters[iii].getFileName() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the casting question, the c-style GDALOpen returns type GDALDatasetH, which you cast to the c++ type GDALDataset. Per the [docs](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a2316f0c00f9997839f782ec946f8303d), GDALDatasetH is an "opaque type used for the C bindings of the C++ GDALDataset class." The mods may ask you to split the question into two separate questions.

Comment: Dear Rob, thank you so much for your answer. It makes more sense now. But I thought you only need to cast a pointer to the type it is pointing to if it is declared as void, however, in the examples from GDAL website they always specify the type of pointer. What they show is:
    GDALDataset *PredictionRaster 
So I thought that when the type of pointer is specified, the conversion of the type from GDALDatasetH to GDALDataset is implicit. I thought that the casting would be necessary in this case:
    void *PredictionRaster
I don't understand either, why GDALDatasets are declared as pointers.

Comment: driver->Create returns a pointer to a GDALDataset so you don't need to use (GDALDataset*) to cast the output from IMGdriver->Create as you have done.

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question asked per question.